# Will a navigation controller recreate/alloc a pushed controller always, or does it cache it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

Consider this code to push a new controller onto the nav stack:

```
   AlphaColorController * a = [[AlphaColorController alloc] initWithColor:color name:name alpha:0.25];
  [[self navigationController] pushViewController:a animated:YES];
  [a release];
```

There is no pointer kept for `a`. If a user navigates into this new controller, then navigates "back", and then "forward" again, is the nav controller smart enough to know this controller is already there, or if it isn't, to allocate it again? How necessary is it to first test (using a pointer) if the controller has been instantiated yet before pushing it multiple times?

UPDATE: putting it another way, will this code effectively re-allocate the controller every single time the user navigates into that particular area of the nav controller? the nav controller is going to rereate and push the newly created controller every time?

Comment: In the above code, yes it will create a new controller every time.  If you set the controller to a property and then checked for nil then you would not need to create it every time.

Comment: will creating it every time in the above manner simply replace the existing allocated instance in the nav controller's array of pushed controller? there is no memory leak here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you understand how your code is operating.  You are, in fact, creating the new view controller object you speak of, and you are, in fact, pushing it onto the nav stack.  And what do you mean not keeping a pointer to it?  That little star ain't there for nothin'!

NavigationControllers keep a reference to their navigation stacks until such a time as a view is popped off the stack.  In which case, said view is deallocated and destroyed.

Comment: there is no pointer after it is gone, no instance variable, my point is, should you check to see if the pushed controller was already created in a previous moment (by creating an instance variable and then checking if the controller for that ivar was already created) when the user navigated through your controller, or will the controller know if it already has the requested controller added to itself.

Comment: NavigationControllers retain their stacks until a view is popped off.

Answer (score 0):

When a navigation controller push a view controller, the pointer of the view controller will be added into the stack of the navigation controller. So the retain counter +1

The the navigation controller keeps all references of the view controllers it pushed.